# Split single row into two rows in a spark dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in spark dataframe like below

```
nm    date        id       amount
1233  2017-01-23  9253194  2323
1234  2017-01-24  9253196  4455
1235  2017-01-25  9253195  5677
```

My output should be

```
1233
2017-01-23  9253194  2323
1234
2017-01-24  9253196  4455
1235
2017-01-25  9253195  5677
```

Can somebody please help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: So your new dataframe only have one column ?

Comment: No. First column in a different row and rest 3 column in a different row

Comment: How many columns does your output dataframe contains.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears you don't want a DataFrame as output, otherwise you'd have similar structure of every row. See if this helps:

// I tried re-creating your dataframe quickly. only for reference, you can skip

```
val myList = List((1233,"2017-01-23",9253194,2323),(1234,"2017-01-24",9253196,4455),(1235,"2017-01-25",9253195,5677))
val myDF = myList.toDF(Seq("nm","date","id","amount"): _*)
scala> myDF.printSchema
root
 |-- nm: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- amount: integer (nullable = false)
```

// And here's how you can print the way you've specified.

```
myDF.foreach(row => println(row.get(0)+" \n"+row.get(1)+" "+row.get(2)+" "+row.get(3)))
```

In case you want it in the DataFrame structure, you'll have to keep 3 fields in each row and then populate one with just one value and the next will all 3 values. It's messy and usually unrealistic to ever need that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to log/print to console the dataframe in that format or continue processing such dataframe.

If you want a dataframe with such structure, the following code produces it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
object Test extends App {
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import sparkSession.implicits._

  val columns = Seq("nm","date","id","amount")
  val input = List(
    (1233, "2017-01-23", 9253194, 2323),
    (1234, "2017-01-24", 9253196, 4455),
    (1235, "2017-01-25", 9253195, 5677)
  )

  sparkSession.createDataset(input).toDF(columns: _*)
    .repartition(1)
    .flatMap {
      case Row(nm: Int, date: String, id: Int, amount: Int) =>
        List[(String, Int, Int)](
          (nm.toString, null.asInstanceOf[Int], null.asInstanceOf[Int]),
          (date, id, amount)
        )
      }
    .foreach(row => Console.println(row))
}
```

but there are some issues:

- there are different types in the first column and the second column, so the first column must be converted
- Spark may repartition the dataset at any row, so the final output may look like that:

`(1233,null,null)
(1235,null,null)
(1234,null,null)
(2017-01-23,9253194,2323)
(2017-01-25,9253195,5677)
(2017-01-24,9253196,4455)`

- because of that writing to any output will produce more or less random result
- now your rows have not consistent number of non-empty columns, if you forget about it you will at some point reference a column/field containing null
- you cannot sort rows
- grouping it again (into rows containing 4 columns) is not possible at all (unless you don't care whether the result is correct)

In summation, if you want to print the rows in that format you should define a function which produces a String from a given row.

If you want to process dataframes with such structure, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done easily with spark sql:

```
sqlContext.sql("select cast(nm as string) from df 
           union all select cast(date as string) + ' ' 
                          + cast(id as string) + ' ' 
                          + cast(amount as string) from df")
```